# Why might this ASP.NET profile section fail to dynamically compile?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-2.0, profile, asp.net-profiles

When the following profile section is in my web.config, the first page request fail with FileNotFoundException and a bunch of error coming from the compiler (from the look of the stack trace). When the properties section is removed, everything works again (until I try to reference something from the Profile of course).  The rest of the website is pre-compiled, assembly per page, not-updatable.

The problem has only been reproduced on one machine-- the same build worked on other highly similar machines.

Am I missing anything obvious?

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
         connectionStringName="ConnectionString"
         applicationName="OIWebApps"
         type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <group name="UI">
      <add name="MasterPage" defaultValue="Horizontal.master"/>
      <add name="Theme" defaultValue="Default"/>
      <add name="IsSessionWarningEnabled" defaultValue="True" type="System.Boolean"/>
      <add name="UseTelerikMultilineTextBoxes" defaultValue="True" type="System.Boolean"/>
      <add name="FontSize" defaultValue="Smaller" type="System.String"/>
    </group>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed to compile because of a missing native .dll  It was extremely hard to identify because the page that was executing didn't directly use the .net dll that depended on the missing native .dll, and even more confusingly, only some pages raised the compile error instead of being raised on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

I see "`UseTelereikMultilineTextBoxes`". Could it be that a file needed for Telerik is missing on this machine?

Comment: No, the various telerik controls load once the properties & profiles section is removed.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if you could catch anything in the events in Global.asax that would provide more information, like Application_Start, Session_Start, Application_BeginRequest, etc.